# covariant return type depending on a template class typedef

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, covariance

Like each time I try to mix generic programming and polymorphism, I have to struggle with my compiler. C++ is fun, but how difficult (well, my brain is quite complicated too, that does not help).

I have written below a simplified but similar situation where I get the same compiler error :

```
template<typename Object>
class Environment;

class Boat {
};

template<typename Object>
class Worker {
public:
    typedef Object      Object_type;
public:
                        Worker() {}
    virtual             ~Worker() throw() {}
    virtual bool        work() = 0;
    virtual const Environment<Object>*
                        env() const=0;
};

template<typename Object>
class Environment {
public:
    typedef Object      Object_type;
public:
                        Environment() {}
    virtual             ~Environment() throw() {}
    virtual Worker<Object>*   
                        spawnWorker() const=0;
};

template<typename Employee>
class Enterprise;

template<typename Object>
class Painter: public Worker<Object> {
public:
    using typename      Worker<Object>::Object_type;
    typedef Enterprise<Painter<Object_type> >       
                        Environment_type;
public:
                        Painter( const Environment_type *env) : enterprise(env){}
    const Environment_type*
                        env() const override {return enterprise; }
    bool                work() override {return true;}
private:
    const Environment_type* const              
                        enterprise;
};

template<typename Employee>
class Enterprise: public Environment<typename Employee::Object_type> {
public:
    using typename      Environment<typename Employee::Object_type>::Object_type;
public:
                        Enterprise() {}
                        ~Enterprise() throw() {}
    Worker<Object_type>*  
                        spawnWorker() const override { return new Painter<Object_type>(this); }
};

int main() {
    Enterprise< Painter<Boat> > enterprise;
    auto painter=enterprise.spawnWorker();
    painter->work();

    delete painter;

    return 0;
}
```

g++ gives the error :

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Painter<Boat>’:
test.cpp:50:7:   required from ‘class Enterprise<Painter<Boat> >’
test.cpp:61:33:   required from here
test.cpp:42:25: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘const Environment_type* Painter<Object>::env() const [with Object = Boat; Painter<Object>::Environment_type = Enterprise<Painter<Boat> >; typename Worker<Object>::Object_type = Boat]’
                     env() const override {return enterprise; }
                     ^
test.cpp:16:25: error:   overriding ‘const Environment<Object>* Worker<Object>::env() const [with Object = Boat]’
                     env() const=0;`
```

and clang++ is maybe simpler to understand :

```
test.cpp:42:25: error: return type of virtual function 'env' is not covariant with the return type of the function it overrides ('const Environment_type *' (aka 'const Enterprise<Painter<Object_type> > *') is not derived from 'const Environment<Boat> *')
                        env() const override {return enterprise; }
                        ^
test.cpp:50:47: note: in instantiation of template class 'Painter<Boat>' requested here
class Enterprise: public Environment<typename Employee::Object_type> {
                                              ^
test.cpp:61:33: note: in instantiation of template class 'Enterprise<Painter<Boat> >' requested here
    Enterprise< Painter<Boat> > enterprise;
                                ^
test.cpp:16:25: note: overridden virtual function is here
                        env() const=0;
                        ^
```

How Can I resolve this issue ? It would be better if the solution still :

- keeps the return types covariant for the env() implementations
- gets the compilator infer the Object template parameter for Environment from the Employee template parameter of Enterprise

Comment: 'override' means that you are exactly matching the fingerprint of the previous function. You *can't* override Worker::env with an ::env that returns a different type.

Comment: And this design is a mess. I strongly encourage you to read up on design patterns, e.g. here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns

Comment: kfsone, I would certainly accept an answer explaining how to improve the design, could you please be a little more constructive ?

Comment: @kfsone, Considering the OP mentioned covariant return types, you [sure can](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd5ff1eac5e6ff54) override with a different (properly covariant) return type.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that the derived class tries to override a function with a different return type. You can solve this by replacing the `Environment_type` definition in `Painter`:

```
typedef Environment<Object> Environment_type;
```

Whether or not this fix makes sense for your ideas, I cannot really tell, but it will give you the idea, I guess.

But the design in general looks a bit weird. Here my central question:

*Do you really want `Worker` to be the root of an inheritance tree and use it for runtime polymorphism? I am asking because you could not mix pointers of `Worker<boat>` and `Worker<house>`. They are completely different things and their virtual functions do not match.*

If you *really* want to use runtime polymorphism, I suggest a non-template base class. For instance, a boat painting enterprise would then just spawn a pointer to a generic worker, not a boat painter. If you need it to really spawn a boat painter, then I'd say that inheritance (in this case for enterprises/environments) is *not* what you want.

If you *really* need base classes (but not runtime polymorphism), you might want to look into CRTP. It looks strange and will probably lead to more questions, but it is a powerful tool and provides another layer of compile time polymorphism.

If you need a certain interface, but not necessarily an inheritance chain however, you might also want to look into type erasure.